# How to Enable css in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I'm using windows server 2008 and IE 11 for application testing,because my business people use this server to test the applications only in I.E 11.0.Application is working in IE 11.0 in my laptop but same thing is not working in server,Please provide help?

Comment: Enable css, that should be by default, no? Can you be a bit more specific. What exactly is happening, what is the expected behaviour, any errors (a 404 in the console for example)?

Comment: Application Drop down arrows,links and images are not loading in ie 11.0

Comment: @RajeshOm is there any other browser in the server that you could use to see if its only happening in IE?

Comment: Hit `f12` and read the console. Are there any asset errors, or any other errors? They would generally be in red.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

**Internet Explorer 11** processes CSS files by default. Since you're not getting images to load either, it sounds like you're paths may be incorrectly set when going from the laptop to the server.

## Example

```
<!-- Set to local development -->
<link href="http://localhost:8888/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Set to production or staging development -->
<link href="http://yourdomain.com/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

- Are you sure you've moved all of the necessary files over to the server?
- Is the server referencing files from your laptop in the code somewhere?
- Are you using absolute or relative paths? Are they set correctly?
- What errors are you getting in the console when viewing on the server?